# Stored procedure doesnt return all data

Tags: c#, datetime, odbc, sybase

I'm using a simple (no joins etc.) stored procedure that is returning one column with a datetime. It returns about 1800 rows

When calling the stored procedure it works fine approx. 5 times out of 6. The sixth time it doesn't get all data and I get the below exception.

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe
>   an un-representable DateTime.

The database is using SyBase and I'm using a OdbcConnection to call the stored procedure.

```
con.Open();
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = sp;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 15;

    result = GetDataFromQuery(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}

private List<Dictionary<String, Object>> GetDataFromQuery(IDataReader reader)
{
    var cols = new String[reader.FieldCount];

    for (var ordinal = 0; ordinal < reader.FieldCount; ordinal++)
            cols[ordinal] = reader.GetName(ordinal);

    var retList = new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var date = reader["PublicationDate"].ToString(); //Here is exception thrown

        retList.Add(cols.ToDictionary(t => t, t => reader[t]));
    }

    return retList;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "with a datetime looking like..."? Is it returning a `DateTime` or a string? (If it's a `DateTime`, it doesn't have a format - whatever happens when you call `ToString` is just whatever `DateTime` does in your culture.)

Comment: Sorry, its returning a datetime

Comment: On the 6th time was does `reader["PublicationDate"]` hold?

Comment: @JonSkeet when adding the values into retList I dont use ToString, but the same exception is thrown (if I comment out var date = ...)

Comment: @JamieRees the exception is thrown without ToString as well, so I can't see what it holds. For ex: var test = reader["PublicationDate"];

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace, please? And ideally the stored proc, cut down to just what's required to reproduce the problem? What database is this talking to?

Comment: @JonSkeet My guess is that the reader doesn't get the time to get all data from DB somehow. I save all the data into a XML, and when it's not working the PublicationDate="Nov  1 2013 12:00A:" Instead of PublicationDate="Nov  1 2013 12:00AM". The database is sybase and I'm using OdbcConnection. The stored procedure is just a simple select (no joins etc) and returns 1800 rows

Comment: I don't understand where XML comes into this - is the data in the database or not? However you *populated* the database is somewhat irrelevant - or may be where the problem stems from, but isn't part of reproducing it.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The data is in the database. I take all the data and save it (for logging) in a XML, where I see the values being corrupt

Comment: I guess the Datetime returned is stored in the database (not computed by the stored procedure)? Can you verify that the database actually holds valid entries?
Could it be that fetching the Datetime always fails at the same record? Can you test to select those 1800 dates without the stored procedure, but with just a query, to test if the problem comes from the stored procedure or not?

Comment: @erg I tried with a query directly from C# and I still had the same problem

Comment: @krillezzz: If it also fails with a "normal" query from C#: Can you test if it always fails on the same record(s)? And if yes, I would check the value of that record directly in the database to verify that the data is actually valid.

Comment: It doesnt fail on the same value. Is have validated the failed ones in DB and they are correct there. Could it be some problems with me executing the SP every minute when testing? (it only takes a second or max two)